# Transform single output to multiple outputs

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp

I have a MCQ dataset which has 2 input variables question and answer, and output variable distractor ( string of 3 independent sub strings separated by comma).

The aim is build a NLP model that generates 3 distractors for each question and answer, that is separated by comma and  must be place between double quotes " ".

Could anyone please help me on achieving this.

Ex : 
Question : We feel unhappy when 
answer : we have a fight with our classmates
distractor : "we get good grades","we become popular","when we become rich"

Answer (score 0):

This is not a simple job.

You could take a look something like

https://telrp.springeropen.com/articles/10.1186/s41039-018-0082-z

https://www.aclweb.org/anthology/W18-0533.pdf